# how to serializable numbers?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have problems to serialize the numbers, I combined.
I combined the device id and identity ID number.

please give me enlightenment to serialize that number.
I know there is a serialization facility in android studio, but i don't know how to use it.

here I provide related code in my work.
how to serialization variable "inputall"?

```
    EditText input_nik;
    Button bt_serialisasi;
    TextView serialisasi_view;
    TextView deviceid;

    final EditText masukkanNIK = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_nik);
    Button serialisasi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_serialisasi);
    final TextView serialisasi_show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serialisasi_view);
    final TextView hpID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deviceid);

    serialisasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String input1 = masukkanNIK.getText().toString();
            String input2 = hpID.getText().toString();
            String inputall = input2+input1;
            serialisasi_show.setText(inputall);//hpID.getText().toString();hpID.setText(input);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you meant you want to persist the data by first making it a serializable?

Comment: Probably, your "serialized" (I'd say "serial") number has become a string, meanwhile.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean when you say `serialize that number`?

Comment: first thanks friends
yes, i want to preserve the data but randomize it using serialization and later can be re-generalized to the original form, i need this to be used as key in file encryption.
thanks. can you give me enlightenment? @ישואוהבאותך

Comment: yes later remain a string after the serialization sir, can you help me please? thanks sir kling klang

Comment: serialization I mean to change the existing number into a new sequence number but retain / not the existing numbers. after the serialization will be used as a key in the encryption. sorry i am weak in english. thanks sir bentaye

Comment: Then what you meant is making them to a sequential number.

Comment: sorry iam wrong. I mean not a sequential number , I mean serialized by maintaining the original number. please help sir thanks @ישואוהבאותך